# ngTagsInput - how to clear results on selection?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Currently, I am making use of ngTagsInput  directive for my search bar. However, I am having trouble finding a way to clear results on selection or prevent the tags from rendering in the search bar.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

I tried writing a directive to detect enter key press down and then use myEnter=$('tags-item').remove() to try and remove the element as it was being created, but not only did it not work, it's also not ideal:

```
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: if you don't want tags, why are you using this component?

Comment: I want tags, but not inside the input field. I just want them inside a div I specify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using this component while you don't actually want the tags.

anyway, you don't need that custom directive. on-tag-added can pretty much cover all you need.

i.e. on , add

```
on-tag-added="tagAdded($tag)"
```

in controller

```
$scope.tagAdded = function(tag) {
   //just do whatever you want on tag added, 
   //i.e. clear the ngmodel and add it to another array, etc.
};
```

Comment: I want to use the component's auto suggest and pillbox feature. Instead of rendering the pillboxes in the input field, I want them to be rendered in a div I specify.

Comment: like I told you in this answer, you can do what you want within the tagAdded callback. for example, clear the ngModel, so you don't see tags in the search box, you then add the tag to another array to be displayed on the div you specify.

Comment: that answer is not ideal because if I'm using autocomplete, and I clear the model, then there is a chance for duplicates in the div I specify.